# How to figure out eigenvalues of a matrix in matlab when all entries of matrix are variables?

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, function-handle

I have a matrix with a bunch of unknown constants such as the one below:

```
  a*b     -c     -d     0
   -c      e     -a    -b-d
   -d     -a      d    -e
    0     -b-d   -e     a
```

As you may realize it is symmetric about the diagonal and therefore, the diagonal values are all positive.  All constants are greater than 0.

I would like to solve this for the eigenvalues in matlab.  How would I go about doing this?  I do not know the values a,b,c,d, and e.  I would like to do something like this:

```
d = eig(@getMatrix)
```

but the eig function does not accept function handles.

Comment: I think you need the symbolic math toolbox for this. If you have it, then the `eig` function works fine with a symbolic matrix as input. See the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/symbolic/eig.html)

Comment: Yep, this is a symbolic problem, and MATLAB is a numerical tool. What you need is a computer algebra system.

Comment: you should do this in a Computer Algebra System such as Maxima. Matlab is not the best tool for symbolic operations.

Comment: @ColinTBowers How would I get that toolbox?  I am using a school computer with matlab pre-installed.  I thought from looking on their website, MATLAB should already have it.  If that is the case, how do I use it?

Comment: @user972276 Type `ver` in the Matlab command window. This will list the installed toolboxes. If the symbolic math toolbox is not listed, but you think it should be, then let the local sys-admin know. Regarding the actual use of the toolbox, I'm afraid I can't help. As several other comments have noted, Matlab is not a great tool for symbolic math. I personally use [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), but if I was starting my life over, I'd use [sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_%28mathematics_software%29) or [maple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_%28software%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem in MATLAB.

```
>> syms a b c d e
>> M = [a*b     -c     -d     0
   -c      e     -a    -b-d
   -d     -a      d    -e
    0     -b-d   -e     a];

>> eig(M)
ans =
 a/4 + d/4 + e/4 + (a*b)/4 - ((51*a*d^3)/16 - (117*a^4*b)/16 + (27*a^3*d)/16 + (27*a*e^3)/16 + (57*b*d^3)/2 + (27*a^3*e)/16 + (27*d*e^3)/16 + (51*d^3*e)/16 + 6*((4*(2*b*d - (a*e)/4 - (a*d)/4 - (d*e)/4 - (a^2*b)/4 + (11*a^2)/8 + b^2 + c^2 + (19*d^2)/8 + (11*e^2)/8 + (3*a^2*b^2)/8 - (a*b*d)/4 - (a*b*e)/4)*((17*a*d^3)/64 - (39*a^4*b)/64 + (9*a^3*d)/64 + (9*a*e^3)/64 + (19*b*d^3)/8 + (9*a^3*e)/64 + (9*d*e^3)/64 + (17*d^3*e)/64 + (45*a^4)/256 + (285*d^4)/256 + (45*e^4)/256 - (a^2*b^2)/16 + (a^2*b^3)/8 + (3*a^2*b^4)/16 + (31*a^4*b^2)/128 + (a^4*b^3)/64 - (3*a^4*b^4)/256 + (3*a^2*c^2)/16 + (15*a^2*d^2)/128 - (9*a^2*e^2)/128 + (19*b^2*d^2)/16 - (b^2*e^2)/16 + (3*c^2*d^2)/16 + (15*c^2*e^2)/16 + 
...

(a*b*c^2*e)/8 + (3*a*b*d*e^2)/64 + (11*a*b*d^2*e)/64 + (a*b^2*d*e)/4 - (33*a^2*b*d*e)/32 - (5*a^2*b^2*d*e)/64 + (a*b*d*e)/4 + (a*c*d*e)/2 - 2*b*c*d*e) - 256*((17*a*d^3)/64 - (39*a^4*b)/64 + (9*a^3*d)/64 + (9*a*e^3)/64 + (19*b*d^3)/8 + (9*a^3*e)/64 + (9*d*e^3)/64 + (17*d^3*e)/64 + (45*a^4)/256 + (285*d^4)/256 + (45*e^4)/256 - (a^2*b^2)/16 + (a^2*b^3)/8 + (3*a^2*b^4)/16 + (31*a^4*b^2)/128 + (a^4*b^3)/64 - (3*a^4*b^4)/256 + (3*a^2*c^2)/16 + (15*a^2*d^2)/128 - (9*a^2*e^2)/128 + (19*b^2*d^2)/16 - (b^2*e^2)/16 + (3*c^2*d^2)/16 + (15*c^2*e^2)/16 + (15*d^2*e^2)/1...

Output truncated.  Text exceeds maximum line length of 25,000 characters for Command Window display.
```

I deleted a lot there. Admittedly, its rather messy and lengthy, but can you really expect better?

Edit: I should comment that such a long extended formula may be dangerous in terms of computational accuracy. I've seen people blindly use such a mess of an expression, evaluating it in Fortran or MATLAB. They think that because it is "symbolic" that it is also exact. This is a total fallacy when numerical computations are done.

There may well be immense subtractive cancellation in those terms, with huge positive and negative terms almost canceling each other out, leaving a tiny result that is essentially worthless because of the limited dynamic range of floating point computations. BEWARE. At the very least, compare single and double precision computations done with the same expression. If they differ by any significant amount, try an extended precision version to verify there is not a problem for the doubles. If you have not tested such an expression and verified it extensively, don't trust it.